# Powershell script syntax issue

Tags: powershell

```
$Source = "[source]"   
$Destination = "[destination]"


xcopy $Source\* $Destination /Y

Get-ChildItem -path $Destination\* -Include *.zip,*.rar,*.7z | %{ 
    if($_.Name -match "^*.'.zip$" -or $_.Name -match "^*.'.7z$" -or $_.Name -match "^*.'.rar$"){
        $parent="$(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent)";    
        $arguments=@("x", "'"$($_.FullName)'"", "-o'"$($parent)'" -y");
        $ex = start-process -FilePath "'"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'"" -ArgumentList $arguments -wait -PassThru;
        if( $ex.ExitCode -eq 0){
            rmdir -Path $_.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}
rmdir -Path $Source\* -recurse -Force
```

When I try to run this script, I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token '$(' in expression or statement.
At D:\Bluedoor\WealthNET Files\Interface Data\RMS\Untitled3.ps1:10 char:32
+         $arguments=@("x", "'"$( <<<< $_.FullName)'"", "-o'"$($parent)'" -y");
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ($(:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but you should try this :

```
$arguments=@("x", "$($_.FullName)", "-o`"$($parent)`"", "-y");
```

in -o argument  `(back quote) allow you to use " (double quote) inside a string delimited by doubles quotes.

```
Get-ChildItem t.txt | % {$parent="coucou";$arguments=@("x", "$($_.FullName)", "-o`"$($parent)`"", "-y");$arguments}
```

gives :

```
x
C:\temp\t.txt
-o"coucou"
-y
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your quotes.  I think you want this

```
$arguments=@("x", ""'$($_.FullName)'"", "-o'"$($parent)'" -y");
```

Comment: Not working man. still throwing error.

Unexpected token '$($_.FullName)' in expression or statement.
At D:\Bluedoor\WealthNET Files\Interface Data\RMS\Untitled3.ps1:10 char:45
+         $arguments=@("x", ""'$($_.FullName)' <<<< "", "-o'"$($parent)'" -y");
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ($($_.FullName):String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken